# Why am I unable to get response from my api using #apisauce?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, postman, apisauce

Response is always returning undefined. I'm calling simple log in service using #apisauce in my react native app. Here's my implementation.

This is the handleSubmit method.

```
import loginApi from '../api/loginApi';

const handleSubmit = async ({email, password}) => {
    const result = await loginApi.login(email, password);
    console.log(result);
    console.log(result.data);
  };
```

Here is the Api call

```
import {create} from 'apisauce';

const apiClient = create({
  method: 'POST',
  baseURL: 'https://...',
  timeout: 10000,
});

export default apiClient;
```

And here's the api layer for login.

```
import apiClient from './client';

const loginApi = (email, password) => {
  apiClient.post('/login', {email, password});
};

export default {loginApi };
```

result always remains undefined. No error, no exceptions, nothing is coming in the result. I've checked the URLs, prams etc on #postman a number of times and everything is alright.

Comment: What's `loginApi`? Because that doesn't exist in your code except when you try to call the `login` method on it.

Comment: We have no way to know what `loginApi` is supposed to be doing. Also what is `apiClient.post` because you're not showing the definition for that.

You're exporting the constant `apiClient` but what does it do? what are its methods?

Comment: @Andy see my question now. I've edited it.

Comment: You should consider reading the answer. It seems it's correct.

Comment: @jabaa yes it's almost solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Result remains undefined because you're not returning anything from your `loginApi.login()` function.

Comment: Thanks, u r right. But now I'm getting 502 bad gateway error. What could be the reason?